# Spring boot send e-mail API REST

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, email

I'm trying to create an API rest to send email
but i'm facing this error:

**cold not autowire no bean of 'javaMailSender' type found  **

Mail Model.java

```
@Data
public class Mail {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String subject;
    private String message;
}
```

this my MailService.java

```
@Service
public class MailService {
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;
    @Autowired
    public MailService(JavaMailSender javaMailSender) {
        this.javaMailSender = javaMailSender;

    }

    public void sendEmail(Mail usermodel) throws MailException {

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("Name: ").append(usermodel.getName()).append(System.lineSeparator());
        sb.append("\n Message: ").append(usermodel.getMessage());

        SimpleMailMessage mail = new SimpleMailMessage();

        mail.setTo(usermodel.getEmail());
        mail.setFrom("emailremoved@gmail.com");
        mail.setSubject(usermodel.getMessage());
        mail.setText(sb.toString());

        javaMailSender.send(mail);
    }

}
```

EmailController.java

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/email")
public class EmailController {
    @Autowired
    private MailService mailService;

    //some other code

    @PostMapping()
    public ResponseEntity<Mail> enviarEmail(Mail email){
        try {
            mailService.sendEmail(email);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(email,  HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch( MailException e){
            return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }


    }
}
```

thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have configured emailsender.

what you should do is create configuration file with this bean like this:

```
@Configuration
public class EmailConfig {
    @Bean
    public JavaMailSender javaMailSender() 
    {
        JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();
        mailSender.setHost("smtp.gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPort(25);
          
        mailSender.setUsername("admin@gmail.com");
        mailSender.setPassword("password");
          
        Properties props = mailSender.getJavaMailProperties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
          
        return mailSender;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing javax.mail dependency.
Add this to pom.xml

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the right dependency into your **pom.xml** ?

I've imported this for my project and it's working:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this Java mail API and javax.activation dependencies to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.7</version>
  </dependency>
```

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/activation -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
    <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```